# EC2 socks proxy, cannot access Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, amazon, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Amazon AWS blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/why-is-amazon-ams-blocked)

I regularly use an EC2 instance as a socks proxy. When visiting Stack Exchange sites, I receive the following error:

> We're sorry...
>   This IP is only allowed to access our API.
>   To protect our users, we can't process requests from this IP address.
>   If you believe you have reached this page in error, contact us.

Are all EC2 elastic IPs blocked? If so, what is the reason? Just curious...