# lynx -dump www.stackoverflow.com restricted ? How filtering works?

Tags: discussion, linux

I tried to dump the content of www.stackoverflow.com using Lynx, but I got the following output.

> # lynx -dump www.stackoverflow.com
>
> ```
> We're sorry...
>
> This IP is only allowed to access our API.
>
> To protect our users, we can't process requests from this IP address.
>
> If you believe you have reached this page in error, [1]contact us.
>
> References
>
>  1. mailto:team@stackoverflow.com
> ```

Why is the content restricted? It is an open site and should be accessible by Lynx.
Do I need to do something else to fetch the content with Lynx?
What's wrong with my IP? I am using Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: If you want to view it in Lynx, there *is* a Lynx version of the SE sites avaliable at http://www.column80.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You commented:

> i am using Amazon EC2 instance

Requests from Amazon's cloud services seem to be [blocked wholesale](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/why-is-amazon-ams-blocked):

> Amazon cloud services are blocked from accessing anything but the API due to a good deal of abuse coming from those services - spammers, scrapers, bots that don't compress their requests and ask for all of our sites causing a good deal of load on our services.

There is probably nothing you can do, short of proxying your requests, or using a different server.

Comment: ...or using the API like the page suggests. [Lots of good stuff here for doing that](http://stackapps.com).

Answer (score 6):

The website *is* accessible by Lynx. It is not accessible from *your IP address*, like the error message says.

> We're sorry...
>
> **This IP** is only allowed to access our API.
>
> To protect our users, we can't process requests **from this IP address.**
>
> **If you believe you have reached this page in error, [1]contact us.**

Comment: hmm i am using Amazon EC2 instance, it should be accessible i believe.

Comment: @Praveen IP addresses from Amazon EC2 instances are intentionally blocked due to abuse.