# Add SE question to Readability, get API access only error message

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Amazon AMS blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/why-is-amazon-ams-blocked)

I added [Have I missed anything from my list of web form best practices?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9898/have-i-missed-anything-from-my-list-of-web-form-best-practices?newsletter=1&nlcode=36226|13a8) to my [Readability](http://www.readability.com/) reading list, it gets sent to my Kindle (and displayed on the website) as:

> Stack Exchange
>   ux.stackexchange.com
>
> This IP is only allowed to access our API.
>   To protect our users, we can't process requests from this IP address.
>   I you believe you have reached this page in error, contact us.

As requested, I'm contacting you. I'm contacted Readability, and pointing them to this question.

(I'm guessing they're using one of the clouds, and you've blocked those IPs. Just a guess. But while I can understand blocking editing, voting, etc. from random cloud VMs, shouldn't anonymous viewing be perfectly safe?)

Comment: Readability uses AWS, which is blocked wholesale due to [a history of being abusive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/why-is-amazon-ams-blocked).