# Unblock AWS for logged in users with sufficient rep?

Tags: support

Per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90021/why-is-amazon-aws-blocked) meta question, you can't connect to SO on a EC2 machine because of past abuse.

Is there a way to allow signed in/authenticated users to see SO?  Or is there something fundamental about the networking techniques being used to block EC2 that would prevent that.

It's not the end of the world to jump back from my remote machine to a local browser.  But then again, rep on the site should serve as a pretty easy check to prevent bad behavior...

Comment: It looks like it might be an IP address block, which means that block is too low level to distinguish between authenticated users.

Comment: hmm wouldn't you have to process the request in order to know that you're authenticated and have the rep thus keeping the request load the same even if the response load was different?

Answer (score 3):

Adding a captcha would be good .. that's how http://whirlpool.net.au deal with the issue